# How can I use JasperFillManager.fillReportToStream?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a simple *Java* program that takes a *.jrxml* file, compiles it, then fills it. The data for the report is supplied in an *XML* file. After the fill is done, the data is exported to *PDF*.

```
// Parse input document
Document document = JRXmlUtils.parse(new File(xmlFile));

// Set it as the data source in the parameters
parameters.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);

// Create and set the virtualizer
JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(2, "/tmp");
virtualizer.setReadOnly(true);
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);

// Fill the report
String jasperFile = designFile.replaceAll(".jrxml",".jasper");
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFile, parameters);

// Export the report to PDF
ArrayList<JasperPrint> jasperPrints = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
jasperPrints.add(print);
JRPdfExporter exp = new JRPdfExporter();
exp.setParameter (JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrints);
exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outFileName );
exp.exportReport();
```

My confusion is about the export

That fill line above works great for small reports, but once I get an *XML* source file approaching 1/2 MB, it will spin for over a day, regardless of setting the file *virtualizer* (which I do).

I see there is another method called `fillReportToSteam`. My confusion is that with `fillReport`, I have to do an extra step to export to PDF. What sort of stream is `fillReportToStream` writing to, and how do I specify that? Will `fillReportToStream` write to a PDF file?

I haven't been able to find any examples. I was hoping I could take advantage of the stream so that I could measure the progress and get these *PDFs* to complete in a normal span of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `fillReportToStream` still produces a `JasperPrint` object, but it writes it directly to an output stream instead of passing it back to you. The `JasperFillManager` cannot output the report in any other format, so the export step cannot be skipped. To generate a PDF, you would still need to use `JRPdfExporter` and read the filled report from wherever the output stream wrote it to.

I think the problem here is your file virtualizer. You mention that "it will spin for over a day, regardless of setting the file virtualizer" but the virtualizer will actually make the process take *longer*. It is a basic time/memory tradeoff to avoid out of memory errors, but will make the filling much slower. In a benchmark I've seen, adding a file virtualizer *quadrupled* the filling time!

If you really need the virtualiser, try increasing the maxSize parameter you are passing. 2 seems awfully low. You could also try switching to a `JRSwapFileVirtualizer` as I've heard they have much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sample of use:

```
    public class ExporterReport {
    private byte[] report = null;
    private String reportName = "myreport";
    protected Collection<? extends Object> getData() {
        //TODO: return your collection
    }
    protected String getReportPath() {
        return "/report/myreport.jasper";
    }   
    public final void buildReportXLS() {        
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            params.put("text", "sametext");
            String reportUrl = getReportPath();
            Collection<? extends Object> collection = getData();
            if (!collection.isEmpty()) {
                URL urlJasper  = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource(reportUrl);
                JRDataSource data = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection);
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
                try {
                     jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(urlJasper.getPath(), params, data);
                     if (jasperPrint != null) {
                        /**
                         * 1- export to PDF sample
                         */
                        //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "C://sample_report.pdf");

                        /**
                         * 2- export to HTML Sample
                         */
                        //JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint,"C://sample_report.html");

                        /**
                         * 3- export to Excel sheet
                         */
                        JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();

                        ByteArrayOutputStream xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, xlsReport);
                        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
                        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
                        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
                        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS,Boolean.FALSE);
                        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,Boolean.TRUE);
                        exporter.exportReport();
                        xlsReport.flush();
                        xlsReport.close();
                        this.setReport(xlsReport.toByteArray());
                     }
                  } catch (JRException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }             

                if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
                    log.info("Report build successful", reportName);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("has a error {0} in {1}: {2} [{3}]", e, reportName, new Date(), e.getMessage(), "information");
        }
    }

    public void downloadReportXLS() {
        if (this.getReport() != null) {
            this.downloadFile(this.getReport(), reportName + ".xls");
        }
    }

    private void downloadFile(byte[] bytes, String fileName) {
        try {
            String contentType = null;
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

            if (fileName.lastIndexOf('.') != -1) {
                contentType = URLConnection.getFileNameMap().getContentTypeFor(fileName);
            }

            if (StringUtil.isStringEmpty(contentType)) {
                contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            }

            response.setContentType(contentType);
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);  
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

            ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            os.write(bytes);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            facesContext.responseComplete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

In your xhtml you can put this :

```
<h:commandButton value="Export to sheet" actionListener="#{exportReport.buildReportXLS()}" action="#{exportReport.downloadReportXLS()}" />
```